# Prove $\sum^n_{i=1} (2i-1)=n^2$ by induction

Tags: induction

The problem is to prove that
$$\sum^n_{i=1} (2i-1)=n^2$$
for all $n \geq 1$ by induction.

Comment: As this is clearly a homework question: how far did you get on your own? Where did you start and where did you end up?

Comment: There are only two possibilities for a person to ask a homework-look question; the first one is that he does not want to do it himself, and the second one is that he simply needs help. I assume not the first one; the point is to understand.

Comment: well to be honest. My problem is how to formulate it properly as Gudson did. this is what I try to understand basically

Comment: The question will be closed sooner than later, making it pointless for anyone to make an effort answering it. Please show your own effort, if you're expecting others to do the same!

Comment: @barakmanos Not every answerer aims at the meaningless "scores"; helping people is an important thing to do. But, yeah right, of course, traditionally a homework-looking question without efforts will be closed soon.

Comment: @GudsonChou: Yes, but if the question is closed, then it is most likely removed within a month, along with your "meaningful" answer.

Comment: @barakmanos Your words just shows that you understand not what I was saying; helping a person understand is more important than whose name is lasting. Hope you can figure out this sooner.

Comment: @barakmanos Thank you for your praise; I am sure my answer is meaningful in the sense that the OP finds it helpful.

Comment: @GudsonChou: To get good help, one should ask good questions. This is not a good question, since it gives no information about what the OP is actually having problems with. And besides, the site is full of hundreds of very similar questions already. Probably this one has been answered before, in which case it should be closed as a duplicate (if only someone will bother to search).

Comment: @HansLundmark Agreed; I see nowhere in my comments goes against yours. The problem is that so many people measure others by their own shoes; just because they help only when they are sure that their efforts are not in vain, does not imply that EVERYone thinks so. To me, that motivation is wrong; they majorly want to get something, and "help" is just a by-product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=1$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1) = 2-1 = 1 = n^{2}$; if $n \geq 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1) = n^{2}$, then 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(2i-1) = n^{2} + 2(n+1) - 1 = n^{2} + 2n + 1 = (n+1)^{2};
$$
by the principle of induction we are done.

Comment: but for n=2, it makes it 3 and there is no n²=3, So it fails. Is this wrong?

Comment: For $n=2$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1) = (2-1) + (4-1) = 1+3 = 4 = n^{2}$. :)

Comment: Right, we have to consider both. not only the the last one. thanks a lot. Now it is all clear.

Answer (score 1):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{1}2i-1=1^2$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}2i-1=n^2$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}2i-1=$

$\left(\color\red{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}2i-1}\right)+2(n+1)-1=$

$\color\red{n^2}+2(n+1)-1=$

$n^2+2n+1=$

$(n+1)^2$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.